# How to remove ID from write.table CSV output

Tags: r

When I execute this statement:

```
write.table(bigdata, 'news.csv', sep = ',')
```

It outputs like this:

```
"type","text"
"1","neutral","The week in 32 photos"
"2","neutral","Look at me! 22 selfies of the week"
"3","neutral","Inside rebel tunnels in Homs"
"4","neutral","Voices from Ukraine"
"5","neutral","Water dries up ahead of World Cup"
"6","positive","Who's your hero? Nominate them"
```

However, I don't want that ID column, the numbers that appear like 1,2,3,4...  I just want this:

```
"type","text"
"neutral","The week in 32 photos"
"neutral","Look at me! 22 selfies of the week"
"neutral","Inside rebel tunnels in Homs"
"neutral","Voices from Ukraine"
"neutral","Water dries up ahead of World Cup"
"positive","Who's your hero? Nominate them"
```

Here is my dataframe:

```
> head(bigdata)
      type                               text
1  neutral              The week in 32 photos
2  neutral Look at me! 22 selfies of the week
3  neutral       Inside rebel tunnels in Homs
4  neutral                Voices from Ukraine
5  neutral  Water dries up ahead of World Cup
6 positive     Who's your hero? Nominate them
```

How can I remove the ID from the output?

Comment: You may just want to call the argument `row.names = FALSE` in the `write.table()` function.

Comment: @ccapizzano Yup, that does it!  Thanks.

Comment: @ccapizzano if you post an answer i will accept it.

Comment: @RichardScriven I couldn't find that one, nice find.

Comment: Also, `write.csv()` can be used for this too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Specifying `row.names = FALSE` in the `write.table()` function will remove that id column.