# In R: make columns subcategories of a total column

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a stacked bar graph of 'Reactions' (likes, wows etc.), in percentages, to Facebook shares over time.

I've scraped and imported the data to R Studio, and cleaned it to the following columns:

> status_published (date-time format), num_reactions, num_likes, num_loves, num_wows, num_hahas, num_sads, num_angrys

To use ggplot's colour variable to visualise the different types of reactions, I want the 3rd to 8th columns to be assigned under num_reactions, possibly using:

```
ggplot(data = I_love_milk, aes(x=Time, y=Reactions)) + geom_point(aes(color=Types))
```

In this case, how do I make the Types of Reactions?

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of the representation of your data you want to get (maybe providing data sample would help), but I think the basic problem is that your data are `wide` data while your need `long` data to create categories.

To transform your data, just use the function `melt` available in the `reshape` package.

See my example below.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
df <- read.table(textConnection('datetime,  num_reactions,  num_likes,  num_loves,  num_wows,   num_hahas,  num_sads,   num_angrys
01/01/2017 10:40,   15, 4,  2,  0,  2,  3,  4
01/01/2017 10:41,   12, 3,  0,  3,  3,  1,  2
03/01/2017 10:42,   19, 4,  4,  2,  4,  3,  2
04/01/2017 10:43,   9,  0,  0,  0,  4,  3,  2
05/01/2017 10:44,   12, 1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  2'), sep=',', header=TRUE)  
melted <- melt(data=df, id='datetime')
g <- ggplot(data=melted, aes(x=datetime, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_point()
g
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, exactly! But error with dataset:
    Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found

Comment: `value` is a column in the `melted` dataframe. the snippet I posted works here

Comment: Yeah worked for me as you wrote it! I figured out the reason it doesn't work with my data is because I have an ID indexing column, but don't know how to remove the line numbers. Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209292/how-to-remove-id-from-write-table-csv-output but still figuring it out. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: the dataframe indexing shall not be a problem. http://i.imgur.com/b79UKYl.png

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I needed to import the data correctly, as: data <- read.csv(file="milk.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", colClasses=c("NULL",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))